# Display all .jpg images from a specific location

Tags: php, html

I have two php files one called employeeDirectory.php and the other api.php.
I am trying to use api.php to get all of the images and then display them on employeeDirectry.php.

employeeDirectory.php

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="<?php include 'api.php'; 
    echo getEmployees($images); ?>"/><br />
</div>
```

api.php

```
function getEmployees($images) {
    $directory = "/employeedirectory/";
    $images = glob($directory."*.jpg");
    foreach($images as $image){
        echo $image;
    }
return $images;
```

Comment: You mean you want to display _the names of the images_ or the images?

Comment: Apart from that: what is your question here?

Comment: I am trying to display the actual images.

Comment: Well, your html marup contains only one single image tag. How do you expect that to display multiple images? You need one image tag per image.

Comment: Correct @arkascha, that is where I am stuck. I'm not sure what to use.

Comment: Let that glob function return an array with all employees and iterate over that array in your view. In each iteration you echo a full img tag.

Comment: I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

employeeDirectory.php

```
 <?php include_once ('./api.php'); ?>
 ...
 <div class="container">
    <?php 
       $images = getEmployees();
       foreach ($images as &$value) 
       {
          echo '<img src="'.$value.'"><br />';
          unset($value);
       }
    ?>
 </div>
```

api.php

```
function getEmployees() 
{
   $directory = "/employeedirectory/";
   $images = scandir($directory);
   foreach($images as $imagePath)
   {
      if (strpos($imagePath, '.jpg') !== false) 
      {
         $images[] = $imagePath;
      }
   }
   return $images;
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I want. Thanks! Got to leave shortly, but I will accept this answer once I implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way I could do...

api.php

```
function showJpgs($dir, $bet = '') {
    $img = glob($dir.'*.jpg');
    foreach ($img as &$i)
        $i = '<img src="'.$i.'" alt=""/>';
    echo implode($bet, $img);
}
```

employeeDirectory.php

```
<div class="container">
    <?php showJpgs('images/', '<br/>'); //Insert what you want to be between the images where is '<br/>'
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
echo $image;
```

To

```
$returnimages .= "<img src='$image'>";
```

Then

```
return $returnimages;
```

Comment: Gonna be more than that, see usage of in employeeDirectory.php.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this code better?

```
<?php
include 'api.php'; ?>
<div class="container">
    <?php getEmployees(); ?>
</div>
```

api.php:

```
<?php
function getEmployees() {
    $directory = "/employeedirectory/";
    $images = glob($directory."*.jpg");
    foreach($images as $image){
        echo "<img src=\"".$image."\"/><br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Isn't this line: foreach($images as $image) missing and amp (&)?

Comment: an ampersand for what? I think this code can show images.

Comment: My bad, I thought the & was required.